# VisualStudio OutOfMemory Exception when embedding exe file in c# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, out-of-memory, embed, exe

How can I embed a big (0.5GB) exe file into a visual c# project and launch the file?
I already tried adding it to the resources but if I select the build action "Embedded Resource" and compile the project, I'm getting an OutOfMemory Exception, if I select the build action "none" or "content", I'm getting an OutOfMemory Exception when I try to access the file from code (By using Properties.Resources.MyApplication or by using this method: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292). 
My PC has 12GB of Ram so that should not be the problem...

Comment: VS being a 32bit application on the other hand might be the problem..

Comment: You won´t *embed* an executable but simply call it. To do so add a reference to that file into your project and call it´s main-method (or whatever it´s entry-point is called).

Comment: Wow. I hope you realize that creating an executable that large isn't a great idea. To start the application, Windows has to load the entire image into memory, and half a gig is still a lot.Even on a fast SSD this is going to take a noticeable amount of time. If the executable embeds a lot of resources it might be better splitting it up into multiple dlls or put the resources somewhere else. Or is it a case of `char make_prog_look_big[1600000];`? ;-)

Comment: @DirkVollmar If you have the business requirement to only have one single big Setup.exe that has to run completely offline and needs to deploy SQL Server 2014 Express (for example) along with your application then embedding such a large file is essentially the only option. And even this single embedded file is at least about 275 MB in size, let alone other potential dependencies that have to be deployed offline as well. So in my opinion there certainly are perfectly valid cases of having huge embedded resources.

Comment: @haindl Why don't you 7zip the exes, extract > run installer > install components > remove extracted files, instead of embedding multiple exes in setup. something similar to http://superuser.com/questions/42788/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-file-after-extraction-from-a-7-zip-self-extracting-a

Comment: @DipenShah That's a valid question, but I don't see how it would improve the situation. In both cases I have a large Setup.exe and in both cases I have some resources that are embedded in this Setup.exe file. (Files in SFXs are just embedded resources as well.) In my case the embedded resources are even zipped before I embed them in my Setup.exe. So I have exactly zero advantages in using an SFX - neither regarding the file size nor related to the simplification of deployment. In contrast, I have one more technological dependency on 7-Zip that can fail. Sorry, but that's not an option for me.